# Get current DNS server used by using Batch code?

Tags: batch-file, dns

**Language: BATCH (USED IN WINDOWS)**

How are you able to get the current DNS server address that you are using? I only need the primary server address, but if you are able to get secondary and tertiary DNS addresses, that would be *much* help too.

I've already figured out 1 way, and it works good.

```
nslookup >dnsnames.txt
findstr Address dnsnames.txt
```

The only thing I don't know what to do with is how to remove the "Address" word that is prior to the DNS address that you are using (You'll see what I mean by typing in `nslookup` in the Command Line. Here's what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Xza.jpg

I've seen how you can remove the "Address" and leave the wanted DNS Address behind
by using FOR /F but that command boggles my mind, So there's no other way but this. You can explain to me how FOR works though.

```
Address: 192.168.0.1
```

This is just for the people who don't understand me yet. I want to remove "Address" but leave "192.168.0.1" behind. *How* can I do that? Also, how may I put the remaining "192.168.0.1", Which is my DNS server , into a VARIABLE?

By the way, This is just a snip of code I want to use in a program that checks internet components. For the full code: http://pastebin.com/RQQkpQ94

If you have some suggestions or answers, please post below. If there is something wrong with my question, Since I'm new here, Notify me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain the usage of the for command in this case

1.- How to get the server (just a example): what you are using `nslookup localhost`. This will output what you have just see. And probably a message error because your dsn doesnt know localhost, that will be supressed sending stderr to nul

```
nslookup localhost 2> nul
```

2.- Filter the output to get just only the address line: Yes, find or findstr are your friends.

```
nslookup localhost 2>nul | find "Address:"
```

3.- Need to split the output line to only get the ip address. As you said, `for` command is used.

`for /f` allows you to exec a command and process its output. It will allow you to split a line in tokens using a set of delimiters. In this case, the output of the command needs to be splitted on the colon (the delimiter), and we get two tokens, the text on the left of the colon and the text on the right of the colon. We only need the second.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('nslookup localhost 2^>nul ^| find "Address:"') do echo %%f
```

EDITED - Added code to show name of the dns server in first line of nslookup and its ip in second line of nslookup, and save the value of the ip address in variable

```
rem clean variable
set "ip="
rem search data
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('echo exit^|nslookup 2>nul') do ( @echo %%f & set "ip=%%f" )
rem remove spaces from variable
set "ip=%ip: =%"
```

Comment: Does this work for the upper line you get in nslookup localhost _Default Server_? I would like it to show the DNS name it retrieves...

Comment: It works the same, but you will need to adapt the text to find to select which line do you want. Or you can not use `find` to filter the text, indicate that you want the two tokens with `tokens=1,2`, so all lines are processed, and depending of first token (that will be in `%%f` variable) then use the value of the second token (that will be in `%%g` variable, not defined but implicit because the two tokens)

Comment: Ah... So I just edit the token value from 2 to 1,2? will they have to be stored in seperate variables? Or isnt there another way that you can just type another FOR /F command with tokens=1?

Comment: Two tokens, two variables. If you are parsing the line, and just have the two values separated, why another for to parse?. Anyway yes, you can use a second for if you need it.

Comment: Okay, I've used a second, but it still won't work. As I've told you, the FOR /F command just boggles my mind. Can you show me how to do it with only 1 line? I put in tokens=1,2 and then...?

Comment: @EpicTonic: Try the included code. If you want to retrieve the data from the two lines, instead of filtering it with find, just process the two lines getting the second token of both.

Comment: Yes, well... It crashed. In `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('nslookup localhost ^| find "Address:"') do set dnsaddress=%%f` Could I just change the token value to 1 as in Line 1 and `find "Address:"` to `find "Default Server:"`? Sorry if I'm annoying you.

Comment: @EpicTonic: `token` indicates the "section" inside the splitted line that you want to retrieve. So, if delimiter is `:`, to get the value, token has to be 2 (the second section of the string). `find` is filtering the output of the nslookup so the code inside the for loop only processes the desired lines. If you need the line with `Default Server`, then yes, you have to change it.

Comment: Sorry for necromancy, I think I understand now. I have a question though, Can you create more than 1 delimiter for the command?

Comment: @EpicTonic, of course. And the option is called "delim**s**". Just include the required characters one after the other. If a space is needed as delimiter, put it at the end just before the closing quote (there are other ways, but involve scaping the full options string). See [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) for more information in ´for´ command. And, of course, you can leave your dark magical arts and start a new question ;)

Comment: I'll try to prevent myself :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why everyone missed this, but the delimeter should be ": " (notice the space after the colon). Without the space, the command will return a space before the IP address.

The version MC ND created did not work for me in Windows 10. It returned an error:

```
2> was unexpected at this time.
```

Matt Williamson's version worked for me, but the delimiter issue still remains.

As I cannot comment yet, I am providing a corrected version that will correctly return the IP address:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('echo quit^|nslookup^|find "Address:"') do echo %%a
```

Comment: You have a good eye. MC ND missed to escape a redirection. I edited his answer. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sed s to remove the Address String?

Something like:

```
sed "s/Address:  //" < dnsnames.txt
```

resp.

```
findstr Address dnsnames.txt | sed "s/Address:  //"
```

should work.

Sed for windows can be downloaded here:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: What *is* "sed"? Is it a command? I tried it on cmd, but it did not work. Is it a required syntax of a command? Please respond. It's not in the cmd help list either. Is it in another scripting language?

Comment: I edited the answer. It now contains a link to Sed for windows. I realized too late that your question aims at a windows shell.

Comment: Ah. I see. So, It outputs the required "192.168.0.1" immediately? What package am I supposed to download, If any, Do you know any other way without downloading external programs?

Comment: Yes. I tested the solution. To remove the empty spaces you have to adjust the sed command to findstr Address dnsnames.txt | sed "s/Address:  //". Of course sed has to be in the system path.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
 for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('echo quit^|nslookup^|find "Address:"') do set DNSIP=%%a
```